# How to Customize the lead in MS CRM 2011?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, crm, outlook-2010

I configured **microsoft dynamics crm 2011 in my outlook express 2010**.before that i was use the trial version.In that trail version i use customize for lead which is comes under the sales.But i configure with outlook after that i cant find the Customization button.**How to enable the customization button in CRM tool bar or how to customize the lead form in crm?**

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Can you please clarify this a little - there is no Outlook Express access to Dynamics CRM. I have answered the customisation button query however the rest of your query is a little unclear, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

The customisations ribbon tab will only show if you have the "System Customizer" security role. You should also be able to access it via the Settings module, then Solutions.

Answer (score 1):

It's supposed to be at *Settings > Customizations > Customize the System*. A new window will pop up. There, you go *Entities > Lead > whatever-you-need-to-customize*.

May I also suggest that prior to that, you'll create a solution (which involves creating a solution provided)? It may seem as an unnecessary step but will pay off in the long run. You'll be able to package your changes and distribute then easier.

Straight off, I can think of two gotchas, though. In order to customize, you'll need to:

- set the current language to base language,
- make sure that the current user has appropriate permissions
- enable customization of custom entities (doesn't apply to *Lead*, though)

Comment: "set the current language to base language" - good call, had vaguely heard this but forgotten again until you mentioned it.

Comment: @AdamV Yeah, it's a real PIA when our dev on-line is in Swedish and we need to demo for an English customer. Can't go on-premise because it's **on-line** capability we're demo-ing. Can't change the base language because MS won't let me (a huge design miss IMnHO). Not worth paying for an account only for the demo and we need to show off the live id account. In the middle of the demo I get the question - show us how you can customize the system. Yeah... Try to explain to them that it's not possible but will be on **their** system. One sounds like an incompetent moron.

Answer (score 1):

Open an individual Lead record - do you see the Customise Ribbon tab there? If so, that's your answer. If not, it seems your role is not system customiser or system administrator.